# Symfony2 expecting String when evaluating subform

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a Comment entity that has a ManyToOne relationship with a FileUpload entity to allow an image to be attached. Here is the relationship in the Comment entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CMSBundle\Entity\FileUpload", cascade={"persist"} )
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $image;
```

The FileUpload entity simply stores some file information in the DB and has a File field to enable uploads in the form. Here is a snippet:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="file_uploads")
 */
class FileUpload {

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
   */
  private $fileExtension;

  /**
   * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
   */
  private $file;
  ...
```

I create the *image* field in the Comment form as follows:

```
$builder->add('image', new \CMSBundle\Form\FileUploadType(), 
    array('required'=>false));
```

Here is where I create the file field in the FileUploadType:

```
$builder->add('file',null, array(
    'required'=>false,
    'label'=>false
));
```

This is working perfectly well in one of my applications, however now I am using it in a different application and am getting the following error message when uploading an image when creating a comment:

```
Expected argument of type "string", "CMSBundle\Entity\FileUpload" given

Stack Trace
1. in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/FileValidator.php at line 119
2. at FileValidator ->validate (object(FileUpload), object(File)) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php at line 862
```

I've tried tracing through the Symfony code to find the problem and the FileValidator seems to be attached to the image field in Comment, which doesn't make sense since I specify that it is a FileUploadType when creating the form. Also this works in a different application so I can see why it wouldn't be working here. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a mistake in your form creation:

```
$builder->add('image', new \CMSBundle\Form\FileUploadType(), 
    array('required'=>false));
```

should be

```
$builder->add('image', \CMSBundle\Form\FileUploadType::class, 
    array('required'=>false));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The passing the ::class is part of Symfony 2.8 and I'm using 2.6, where you pass an instance of the type instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had an old validation.yml file that was telling the image field in the Comment that it was a File.

```
CommentsBundle\Entity\Comment:
properties:
    image:
        - File:
            maxSize: 6000000
```